# How should I configure clangd to make it scan the library I download with CMake FetchContent?

Tags: c++, cmake

I use CMake FetchContent to download nlohmann/json. But my clangd doesn't scan the library after downloading. So how should I configure my clangd?

my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(ExampleProject LANGUAGES CXX)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(json URL https://github.com/nlohmann/json/releases/download/v3.11.2/json.tar.xz)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(json)

add_executable(example main.cc)
target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json)
```

and my code main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main()
{
    json object = { { "one", 1 }, { "two", 2 } };
    std::cout << object << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

my clangd says:

```
main.cc|2 col 10-29 error| 'nlohmann/json.hpp' file not found
main.cc|4 col 14-22 error| Use of undeclared identifier 'nlohmann'
main.cc|8 col 5-9 error| Unknown type name 'json'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now I know how to solve this problem.

When using CMake, set `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` to 1, to make CMake generate the file `compile_commands.json`. Clangd will automatically scan this file and follow it to scan for third-party libraries.